# Scrollable Tabs in Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-viewpager

So im trying to create a custom dialog box which would contain 2 scrollable screens
[image]

I am trying to achieve this by using a `ViewPager` in the xml of DialogBox and adding two `Fragments` in its `Adapter`

```
    public class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog
    {
Context context;
ViewPager viewpager;


public Custom_Dialog(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.c_dialog);
    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.c_dialog_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewpager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewpager)
{
    FragmentManager manager = null;
    try
    {
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) context;
        manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    } catch (ClassCastException ec)
    {

    }
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(manager);
    Frag_one f1 = new Frag_one();
    Frag_two f2 = new Frag_two();
    adapter.addFragment(f1, "f1");
    adapter.addFragment(f2, "f2");
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
    {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title)
    {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
} }
```

but i am getting this **error**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.fragmentindialog, PID: 26790
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0069 (com.test.fragmentindialog:id/custom_dialog_viewpager) for fragment Frag_two{65ad03a #0 id=0x7f0c0069 android:switcher:2131492969:1}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

here is the **MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
    {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Custom_Dialog dialog =new Custom_Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
}}
```

Both the fragments are just inflating views of different colours.
problem is somewhere in  `viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: Use a dialog fragment . it will make it easier.

Comment: that won't help, dialog fragment is just one single fragment. my purpose is to have 2 fragments

Comment: use DialogFragment instead of Dialog. And use the same code that you currently using.

Comment: did it, same error

Comment: Use getChildFragmentManager() for inside fragments.

Comment: did it, same error, are you testing it yourself first?

Comment: Yes it is working for me. Could you post your codes?